# Differentiating an extensive variable , $V(\alpha N_s,\alpha N_p) = \alpha V(N_s,N_p)$ with respect to $\alpha$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am trying to differentiate the following equation with respect to $\alpha$:

$V(\alpha N_s,\alpha N_p)=\alpha V(N_s,N_p)$

The RHS is simply $\frac{d}{d\alpha}(\alpha V) = V$

Coming to the LHS, $dV = \frac{\partial V}{\partial(\alpha N_s)}d(\alpha N_s) +\frac{\partial V}{\partial(\alpha N_p)}d(\alpha N_p)$
Therefore, $\frac{d(\alpha N_s)}{d\alpha}= N_s$, since ($\frac{dN_s}{d\alpha}=0$).
Thus, I am left with $\frac{dV(\alpha N_s,\alpha N_p)}{d\alpha}= \frac{\partial V}{\partial(\alpha N_s)}N_s +\frac{\partial V}{\partial(\alpha N_p)}N_p$
Am I doing something wrong, as I should be getting $\frac{\partial V}{\partial N_s}N_s +\frac{\partial V}{\partial N_p}N_p = V$.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! What is $V$? what are $N_s, N_p$ exactly?

Comment: Apologies for not expressing clearly, I didn't think they would be important. $V$ is the volume of a solution, $N_s$ is the number of solvent particles and $N_p$ is the number of solute particles. $\alpha$ is just a scaling factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial \alpha} &=& \frac{\partial V}{\partial (\alpha N_s)} \frac{\partial (\alpha N_s)}{\partial \alpha} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial (\alpha N_p)} \frac{\partial (\alpha N_p)}{\partial \alpha} \\
&=& \frac{\partial V}{\partial (\alpha N_s)} N_s + \frac{\partial V}{\partial (\alpha N_p)} N_p
\end{eqnarray}

Now the trick is that you set $\alpha = 1$ and get

$$
V(N_s, N_p) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial N_s} N_s + \frac{\partial V}{\partial N_p} N_p
$$

Comment: But, $\alpha$ can be any number, why are you setting it to be 1?

Comment: @Nine_Gardens Your last expression in the post, doesn't depend on $\alpha$ either

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand. :/

Comment: @Nine_Gardens you can think of it as a dummy variable, you can set it to any value, in particular to $1$